# Bookmark certain page on site regardless of what page your on for iPhone when adding to home screen?

Tags: iphone, bookmarks, cache-manifest

On an iPhone when you bookmark a site and 'Add to Home Screen', is it possible to make a certain page in the site be the bookmark regardless of what page the user was on?

Im working with the cache manifest to make part of my site available offline. Im only interested in a certain section, so I want a certain page to be the first thing users see when they load the site offline.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this is impossible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to differentiate what the current page looks like if the user opens the site from a bookmark on the home screen. This might not be exactly what you are asking for, but might suit your needs just as well.

Comment: I dont think that will work for me. I dont want to bother caching the entire site. If a user bookmarks the home page, I still want them to go section I am caching when offline.